# Why is it that $h''(u)(1+l'(v)^2) + l''(v)(1+h'(u)^2) = 0 $ implies that $\dfrac{h''(u)}{1+h'(u)^2} = -\dfrac{l''(v)}{1+l'(v)^2}$ is a constant?

Tags: calculus

Obviously $h''(u)(1+l'(v)^2) + l''(v)(1+h'(u)^2) = 0 \implies \dfrac{h''(u)}{1+h'(u)^2} = -\dfrac{l''(v)}{1+l'(v)^2}$, but I can't see how those have to be constant. I tried to find a contradiction but couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because $u$ and $v$ are independent, fix $v_{0}$,  so given $ u_{0} \neq u_{1}$ you have 
$\dfrac{h''(u_{0})}{1+h'(u_{0})^2} = -\dfrac{l''(v_{0})}{1+l'(v_{0})^2} = \dfrac{h''(u_{1})}{1+h'(u_{1})^2} $.

Answer (score 2):

If you differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to $u$, the right side has no $u$s, so you get zero.  What does it mean when the derivative with respect to $u$ is zero?  This says the left side, which contains $u$s, is constant as $u$ is varied.  Repeating by differentiating with respect to $v$, the left side is zero, so the right side (which contains $v$s) must be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Because one side is independent of $u$ and the other side is independent of $v$, so this quantity is independent of both of these variables.